# piwik not in webapp

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-applications, piwik

I try to install piwik on my windows server and already found out, that it is not possible to install it from command line, because `cacls` does not work even in administrator mode, because some directories have only write permission through webapp installer ([look here](https://serverfault.com/questions/383926/cacls-access-is-denied)).

First I thought, hey this is great, another fancy GUI interface for installing packages, and even better: there is a webapp version of piwik... [here](http://piwik.org/blog/2010/08/piwik-on-web-app-gallery/)!

But using the provided downloader opens the windows webapp installer window, but there is no piwik showing up. And  I also cannot find it manually in the gallery.

This is a

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
- 64 bit
- SP 1
- ISS

Any idea why I cannot find the piwik version?

Comment: Piwik comes in a zip file too, why not just download and set it up yourself?

Comment: Hi @fuero, as I said, to set it up myself, I need to set write permissions to particular directories, which I don't have permissions to myself, although I run them as admin. The only way to install certain products (like piwik) is AFAIK by employing the webapp installer. I will post the link [again](http://serverfault.com/questions/383926/cacls-access-is-denied). yours, m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is easy:

My feed was not up-to-date, so find yourself the most recent Windows Feed `XML` file online and save it on your server. Then let the path of your Windows Web App Installer point to the path and restart the program.

I still have not found a way to install Piwik from command line.